# ShinyApp Function not returning Result

Tags: r, shiny, shinyapps

I need help with the below shiny app server function. My problem is `values$npv` always comes out null, not even with a `0`. and I think the `fun` function is not doing the right thing and i'm out of ideas.
If I hard-code the `renderText` with `paste("Net Present Value:", isolate(input$val_inv))` i always have a result but not what i want and this makes me guess the `fun` function is not working as it should.

```
     inline_numericInput=function(ni){
  tags$div( class="form-inline",ni)
}

ui <- shinyUI(fluidPage(
  tags$head(tags$style("#side_panel{
                       padding-left:10px;
                       }
                       .form-group {
                       margin-bottom: 15px !important;
                       }
                       .form-inline .form-control {
                       width:80%;
                       }
                label{ width:30px;}

                       ")),

  titlePanel("Example"),

  sidebarLayout(

    sidebarPanel(width = 4,id="side_panel",
                 fluidRow(
                   column(6, inline_numericInput(numericInput("val_inv", label = "Inv:", value = 0))),
                 ),
                 fluidRow(
                   column(6, inline_numericInput(numericInput("val_r", label = "R:", value = 0))),
                 ),
                 fluidRow(
                   column(6, inline_numericInput(numericInput("val_n", label = "N:", min = 50,value = 50))),
                   column(6, inline_numericInput(actionButton("btn_calcnpv", label = "Compute NPV")))
                 )

    ),

    mainPanel(
      p('Results:'),
    textOutput("val_npv")
    )
  )
))

server <- function(input, output) {

    values <- reactiveValues()
    values$npv <- 0

    observe({
        input$btn_calcnpv
        fun <- function(n){
            cf <- 0
            for (i in 1:n){
               cf <- cf + isolate(input$val_inv)/(1+input$var_r)**i
            }
            cf
        }
        values$npv <- fun(isolate(input$val_n))- isolate(input$val_inv)
        #values$npv <- values$npv - isolate(input$val_inv)
    })

    output$val_npv <- renderText({
        if(input$btn_calcnpv)
            paste("Net Present Value:", values$npv)
        else ""
    })

}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Comment: Please, provide a working example.

Comment: In addition to the previous comment, see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) to know how to make a reproducible example

Comment: I have give the entire code.

Comment: Please, check the names of your input variables: val_r versus var_r. Furthermore, I suppose that input variables are characters. Maybe, you have to coerce them to numbers.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an answer using eventReactive and not so many isolations.
Furthermore, the inputs are coerced to numbers before the calculation takes place.
Using eventReactive, the calculation is started by pressing the compute-button.

```
server <- function(input, output) {


  npv <- eventReactive(input$btn_calcnpv, {

    val_inv <- as.numeric(input$val_inv)
    val_r <- as.numeric(input$val_r)
    val_n <- as.numeric(input$val_n)
    fun <- function(n){
      cf <- 0
      for (i in 1:n){
        cf <- cf + val_inv/(1+val_r)**i
      }
      cf
    }
    temp <- fun(val_n)- val_inv
    temp
  })

  output$val_npv <- renderText({
      req(npv())
      paste("Net Present Value:", npv())

  })

}
```